# Display custom tags on the display view of CKEditor 4

Tags: html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm trying to store a string of text in a database that includes custom html tags like:

<inline type="example" />

When it goes into the database it stores just fine but when I try to bring it out of the database into CKEditor to edit/modify it's not visible on the display side. Since it's a custom tag, I just want the person modifying to be able to see it and not CKEditor to try to render the html of it. I've looked some at Advanced Content Filtering but haven't been able to quite figure it out yet.

Any ideas?